# Codeigniter Message: Undefined variable: infos

Tags: codeigniter

I am a newbie in CI. I used MY_Controller.php as main controller. I could open the ajax as the div#page loader. Now , My problem is although I load /about page, I get the database entries for the services model. How can i get the about table for the about controller ?

```
..
    function render_page($view) {
        if( ! $this->input->is_ajax_request() )
        {
          $this->load->view('templates/header', $this->data);
        }
        $this->load->view($view, $this->data);

        if( ! $this->input->is_ajax_request() )
        {
         $this->load->view('templates/menu');
         $this->load->view('templates/footer', $this->data);
        }
      }..
```

My services_model:

```
class Services_model extends CI_Model {

    function getAll() {
        $q = $this->db->get('services');
        if($q->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($q->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;

            }
        return $data;
    }
    }
}
```

My home controller :

```
public function view($page = 'home')
{
$this->load->helper('text');
$this->data['records']= $this->services_model->getAll();
if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
{
    // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
show_404();
}
$data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter
$this->render_page('pages/'.$page,$data);
}
```

When I use them in the home view there is no problem I can see the services_table :

```
<ul class="blog-medium">
<?php foreach($records as $row): ?>
<li>    
<div class="blog-medium-text">
<h1><a href="./post.html"><?php echo $row->title; ?></a></h1>
<p class="blog-medium-excerpt"><?php  echo $row->content; ?><br />
<a href="./post.html" class="read_more">Devamını Okumak için &rarr;</a></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I want to use the same way in about page. 
About_model:

```
class About_model extends CI_Model {
    function getAll() {
        $q = $this->db->get('abouts');
        if($q->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($q->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;

            }
        return $data;
    }
    }
}
```

About controller :

```
 public function view($page = 'about')
    {
    $this->load->helper('text');
    $this->data['records']= $this->about_model->getAll();
    if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
    {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
    show_404();
    }
    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter
    $this->render_page('pages/'.$page,$data);
    }
```

And this is my view file of about :

```
<div id="content">
<?php foreach($infos as $row): ?>
<h3 style="text-align: center;"> <?php echo $row->title; ?></h3>
<div class="hr">    </div>
<?php echo $row->content; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I get the error telling me :

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: infos
Filename: pages/about.php
Line Number: 3
```

Why cant i get the abouts table?

Comment: Could it be that you wanted to write `$records` in the about view file instead of `$infos`? In the about controller you assign to ` $this->data['records']` not to `$this->data['infos']`.

Comment: I changed $this->data['infos'] still same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a variable `$infos` in your `foreach`, but it is never passed in as a variable to your view.

Read the docs about [Adding Dynamic Data to the View](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)

You will either need to set `$data['infos']` to something or, and I'm guessing this what you intended, use `$records` in your `foreach`

The above answers your specific, but after you provided the repo for your source, there are issues you are struggling with. I *highly* suggest you read through the entire documentation, staring with the [Introduction: Getting Started](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/getting_started.html), continuing to the Tutorials and then General Topics.

The reason you are having problems here, you have your routes.php setup to that everything is routed into the `Home` controller executing the `view` method. This method, while it accepts the page you want to see is always returning a fetch of the services model. Your other controllers are not getting executed at all. Based on your controller setup, if you would just remove the custom route, `http://theurl/about` would route to the `About` Controller. The default method to be loaded is `index` so if you change view to index, then it would be displayed by default.

Comment: If I use records. I get the results of services model .

Comment: There seems to be some funny stuff in your rendering logic, I'm going to update my answer. One sec

Comment: Ryan , I tried $data['records']= and $data .. If I use as that even my home view gives me .. Undefined variable: records. Can you give me more information?

Comment: You really need to read through their documentation and understand how PHP Classes and variable scoping work. If you want to upload the model, view and controllers to gist.github.com (you can put multiple files in a single gist) that will provide some insight, but with the limited info above I can't make many more assumptions

Comment: I am learning day by day .I read a lot but always there is more.. Thank you for suggestion Ryan. I shall work much more.

Comment: I understand; If you will post the full files to a single gist.github.com I can see the full picture and can provide more help.

Comment: I made my routes file as $route['default_controller'] = "index";

$route['(:any)'] = 'home/view/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';   but now I get 404 error. how can I use index controller to show the page?

Comment: I think you need to know what a controller is; You don't have a index controller. You controllers are Home, About, Menu, News and Welcome. I was referring to Index as the view function. By default if you where to goto /news/index. It would load the index function from the News controller

Comment: Hmmm in MY_Controller. I only have render_page function but no index function. That makes all the stuff confusing for me. I have to recode my files with index function . Am i right?

Comment: Thanks . I added about in the routes it works now. But I will obey your suggestion and read more.